# Deploying angular-fullstack to Azure

Tags: angularjs, azure

Hi I was wondering how I can deploy angular-fullstack to Azure, I have looked around but can't find any tutorials etc. Can anybody provide any instructions or examples?

https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

Comment: This question is off topic, as it is a request for an off-site tutorial or other resource.  However, I can offer a suggestion:  Azure does not directly support MEAN applications fully in Azure Websites (no mongo hosting), but MEAN applications are fully supported on deployed Azure VMs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is you have two problems to solve to get this into azure.

1. How do I best host my mongo db?
2. How do I publish my node.js application as an azure app?

Answers.

1. Deploy your mongo db either using a VM or a managed mongodb service from the marketplace.

   a. Worker role option: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-azure (worker role mongo db)

   b. Managed Mongo Hosted Azure Service - You can find this from the marketplace from your azure console/portal. (Note that not all regions apply and its not cheap)
2. To deploy your node.js app you have two options.

   a. 
   Create an azure app and hook up the source control so that it will deploy on every commit.

   This is the step by step guide from MS https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-develop-deploy-app/

   b.

   > To publish, run the Publish-AzureServiceProject cmdlet as follows:
   >
   > ```
   > Publish-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName NodeHelloWorld -Location "East US" -Launch
   > ```
   >
   > -ServiceName specifies the name for the deployment. This must be a unique name, otherwise the publish process will fail.
   >
   > -Location specifies the datacenter that the application will be hosted in. To see a list of available datacenters, use the Get-AzureLocation
   >   cmdlet.
   >
   > -Launch opens a browser window and navigates to the hosted service after deployment has completed.

   To get the full info on deploy node apps to azure check out the microsoft docs, its pretty comprehenssive with screenshots too. 
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-develop-deploy-app/